# Free Memory array error after a recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, function-definition

this is my code, the recursive operation is supposed to create array 3, (dynamically) and take a letter from array 1 and a second letter from array 2 until one of the arrays ends.
This works for me, but when I try to FREE the third dynamically created array, I get an error message
the code:

```
void Mirage(char list1[], char list2[], char list3[], int m, int n);
int main()
{
    char array[7] = { 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g' };
    char array2[3] = { 'T','Z','W' };
    char *array3 =(char*) malloc(sizeof(array)+sizeof(array2));
    Mirage(array, array2, array3, 7, 3);
    printf("%s", array3);
    free((void*)array3);

    
}

void Mirage(char list1[], char list2[], char list3[], int m, int n)
{
    if ((m <= 0) && (n <= 0)){
        list3[m + n] = 0;
        return;
    }
        else if (m >= 0 && n <= 0)
        {
            list3[0] = list1[0];
            Mirage(list1 + 1, list2, list3 + 1, m - 1, n);
        }
        else if (m <= 0 && n >= 0)
        {
            list3[0] = list2[0];
            Mirage(list1, list2+1, list3 + 1, m, n-1);
        }
        else
        {
            list3[0] = list1[0];
            list3[1] = list2[0];
            Mirage(list1 + 1, list2 + 1, list3 + 2, m - 1, n - 1);
        }
}
```

the error:
[image]

why am i getting it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `list3[m + n] = 0;` is out of bounds of the array if they are both negative. This error usually means you've written outside the array bounds somewhere. If it was a [mcve] I'd copy/paste it and run it with AddressSanitizer to find out where, but it isn't. You can use tools like AddressSanitizer to find out for yourself though or just step through the code in a debugger and verify that all of the indices you write to are valid.

Comment: Thanks Mate! I changed it to list3[(m + n)-1] = 0; and it works, but i didnt get the rest of the list, so am i still out of bound?

Comment: If "works" means you changed it to something that doesn't make sense but doesn't crash right now then I guess you're okay.

Comment: So how do you propose?
Why am I writing CHAR outside the bounds of the array if I still stay under the indexes?

Comment: Dunno what your program is supposed to do and can't run it, so you're on your own. If you are sure that negative index is within the range of the original allocation then I guess you're fine. Still seems like a guess to me.

Comment: You've written `Mirage` in such a complicated way that it's too complicated for you to debug. Better would be to have an index variable `i` that counts upwards from 0 to go through the arrays, and no recursion. Also `array3` needs to be one character larger if you want to null-terminate it. eg: https://gist.github.com/paulhankin/f8ed1f77dbdb1277144f420882e50796

Answer (score 0):

You are going to output the array `array3` as having a string

```
printf("%s", array3);
```

But you did not reserve a space for the terminating zero character `'\0'` in the array `array3`

```
char *array3 =(char*) malloc(sizeof(array)+sizeof(array2));
```

You have to write

```
char *array3 = malloc( sizeof( array ) + sizeof( array2 ) + 1 );
```

The function should be declared like

```
void Mirage( const char list1[], const char list2[], char list3[], size_t m, size_t n);
```

That is the parameters `list1` and `list2` should have the qualifier `const` because the arrays are not changed within the function. And the sizes of tрe arrays should have the type `size_t`.

The function can be defined the following way

```
void Mirage( const char list1[], const char list2[], char list3[], size_t m, size_t n)
{
    if ( m != 0 )
    {
        *list3++ = *list1++;
        --m;
    }

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        *list3++ = *list2++;
        --n;
    }
           
    if ( m == 0 && n == 0 )
    {
        *list3 = '\0';
    }
    else
    {  
        Mirage( list1, list2, list3, m, n );
    }
}
```

Th call of `free` can be written simpler

```
free( array3 );
```